# ASP.NET caching startup values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching

I'm converting an application from C# WebForms to MVC.

The application gets settings from a centralized location using Web Services.  These are settings you would typically find in a Web.Config, but the desire of the company is to store these values in a centralized location for all apps.

Currently, any time you request an application setting, it checks HttpContext.Cache to see if you've already retrieved the settings.  If you haven't, it makes the web service call, and stores the settings (100+ objects that are essentially key/values) in the HttpContext.Cache.  So the call to get application settings only occurs once.

Should I be looking at another way to do this?  I was thinking the settings should just be a REST service call where you pass the key and get a value (the current service is an *.ashx which is really not ideal for exception handling amoung other reasons).  But obviously this would result in more web requests.  What is considered a best practice here?  Is the current method fine and I should just leave the code working the same in the MVC app?

Comment: StackOverflow is not really the best place to ask this type of question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Where do you suggest?  Thanks.

Comment: Cannot see any issue with asking this on SO?  Seems a fair question in migrating from webforms to MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to load all resources in one call:

- fewer HTTP requests are better for performance. Http requests can have a latency around 50 ms thus it will take much longer to get all values one by one 50 x 100 = 5000 ms => 5 secs
- if the external web service goes down then your application still works because you already downloaded and cached all values

I will keep the current solution if it works and focus on new things instead of rewriting a working code.

Comment: Thanks this is helpful.  The part that still bothers me is using an *.ashx, which seems to be very limited in it's responses as opposed to HttpResponse codes available when using a REST service such as Web API.

Comment: @RyanLangton http handlers could return any type of data (xml, json) and accept any type of requests (also PUT, DELETE). I will recommend to switch to Web API once you need to support multiple type of requests e.g. create/update config values, filtering, deleting values.